# Preventing Firefox dialog box when displaying PDFs in iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe, download, embed

I embedded a PDF file in my site by iframe, And the Firefox is configured to "Always ask" for downloading PDFs.

Now I want to prevent Browser to show "What should Firefox do with this file?" dialog box and instead show the PDF in iframe. I have no problem with downloading the file by users and even created a separate file download button; Actually, I want to always display the PDF file in the iframe regardless of the user's browser settings.

[prevent Browser to show download dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyWyx.jpg)
[prevent Browser to show download dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ox7D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to ask all your users to not use FireFox nor any browser since A PDF

- 1. MUST Download to be edited into a devices window as pixels
- 2. clients do not have to download an exploitable PDF thus you will get a "NO SHOW"
- 3. its the clients choice of browsing
- 4. its the clients settings decide if a PDF (possibly insecurely provided) is allowed to be returned to their browser for display in page or new tab or same tab or in my Firefox a NO JavaScript allowed PDF plugin.